# How to use a definitions in a swift dictionary with an array (Dictionary<String, [String]>) to display on tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Ok first thing first, what am I trying to do? Well I am trying to run something that is like a tag system where it filters out the data with the post by using a dictionary String, [String] type and displays it to the screen. I already figured this out on the console level, but I am stumped on how to do it with this which is kind of weird. I try and it returns nil inside the UI ,but works perfectly on the console level.

Simplified. I want the quick tags filtered array to show up in the tableview

I am repeating this again, console works perfect, but the UI gets wacky and returns nil or does nil. Ok here is the code.

Not 100% sure about this area causing problems ,but I displayed here just in case.

```
//this is the part where I add the stuff into the console
//and add the dictionary part.
@IBAction func ReplyAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if !(TextFieldForComments.text?.isEmpty)! && TextFieldForComments.text != nil
        {
            CommentGlobals.shared.addToCommentSection(newElement: TextFieldForComments.text!)
            let tagCheck = TextViewForComment.text
            if  !quickTags.FilteredComments.keys.contains(TextViewForComment.text){
                quickTags.FilteredComments.updateValue(["\(String(describing: TextFieldForComments.text))"], forKey: tagCheck!)
                print("Hey here is the dictinary you wanted \(quickTags.FilteredComments)")
            }
            else {
                quickTags.FilteredComments[tagCheck!]?.append(CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.last!)
                print("Hey here is the dictinary you wanted wo wo \(quickTags.FilteredComments)")
            }
            TextFieldForComments.text = ""


            //this line of code is important or it
            //won't insert the table view right.
            CommentFeed.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }
```

Here is the problem area

```
//this is the problem area
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let ceal = CommentFeed.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentFeed", for: indexPath)

        //guard let selectedDictionary = quickTags.FilteredComments["\(TextViewForComment)"] else {return ceal}

//this is the part that works, but noted it out for reference
//this doesn't work for what I am trying to do because
//I don't want to display the comments of every view 
        //ceal.textLabel?.text = "\(CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection[indexPath.row])"



 //this is failure. I also tried another way ,but it just printed nil 
    //on to the UI
            //ceal.textLabel?.text =  "\(selectedDictionary[indexPath.row])"


        return ceal
    }
```

Ok if you need more information, please let me know.

Oh yea I can't say this enough it works on a console level perfectly, but not when I try to get it onto the UI.

I also stored the quick tags in a static array, and I stored the rest in a singleton

Here is the expected output (UI)

```
comment
comment
comment
```

the current output is like this(UI)

```
 (it does nothing, runs nil, or crashes)
```

some other sources lead the thing to be like this

```
comment comment comment
```

all of them on the same line which is not what I want.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
//        return CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count
        print(quickTags.FilteredComments.count)
        return CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count
    }
```

Comment: Please include your expected output and the current output.

Comment: oh sorry will get to it right away

Comment: @Samah There it is.  The console works well showing all the comments with their associated tags (not what I want in the UI). Once I try to display a key then it does nil, crashes, or does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView`s do not contain their own data set, they take it from the `dataSource`.  `insertRows(at:, with:)` is only for cell animation, and should be wrapped with `begin`/`endUpdates()`.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBAction func ReplyAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // ...
        CommentFeed.beginUpdates()
        CommentFeed.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        CommentFeed.endUpdates()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentFeed", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Edit: Note that your data set's number of rows and sections MUST match the expected results at the end of the animation, or you will get an exception when calling `endUpdates()`.

Comment: Ok I will try it and get back to you right away. I am grateful for taking your time to do this.

Comment: I am trying to get the quicktags.filteredfeed onto the tableview which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please show your implementations of `numberOfSections(in:)` and `tableView(_:, numberOfRowsInSection:)`.

Comment: func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
  `      return 1`
 `   }`
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
//        return CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count
        print(quickTags.FilteredComments.count)
        return CommentGlobals.shared.commentSection.count
    }

Comment: Are you able to upload a project with a minimal, complete, and verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I guest I can clean up the code a little more and upload it via git hub or dropbox

Comment: Please make an simple example project that displays the problem, and upload it to github.

Comment: I mentioned the problem is that it crashes into nil or just displays nothing at all. I'll post the globals code in your preferred way if you want. when I try to add the thing into a tableview.